# Matlab - add number to single field or vector while keeping other fields unchanged

Tags: matlab, addition

I have the following problem. I have a vector and would like to add a single number to a specific field. I guess this is rather easy but I still need your help.
The vector is valuesforp1 and writes values for every loop iteration (index is yr). After the loop finishes, I want to add the variable "x" into the field of the last loop iteration so into the field (1,yr)
I tried:

```
valuesforp1= x+valuesforp1(1,yr)
```

but logically this gives back a single value rather then the edited vector.
Any ideas how to solve this ? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a number to an array after a determined value:

```
ind     = 10 %position of your value.

MyArray = [MyArray(1:ind),MyNewNumber,MyArray(ind+1:end)]; %for a horizontal array

 MyArray = [MyArray(1:ind);MyNewNumber;MyArray(ind+1:end)]; %for a vertical array
```

if you want to replace a determined number of the array:

```
MyArray(ind) = MyNewNumber;
```

if you want to change a value to obtain (theValue+NewNumber):

```
MyArray(ind) = MyArray(ind)+MyNewNumber;
```

Comment: its unfortunately not the last number - its is in the middle of the array - is there anyway to replace that number ?

Comment: Yes, of course, but you want to add a new value or replace a value ?

Comment: I want to replace it